# Google App Engine tomcat error with Spring Boot

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, springboot

First of all, I am a real newbie using any cloud services, and this is the first time that I have asked something here, therefore I am apologizing in advance if anything I may say is wrong.

I'm trying to deploy a Spring Boot app using Google Cloud Platform's App Engine, locally it is **running** exactly how it should on Eclipse (I'm using the GCP tool for Eclipse), but when a try to **deploy** it on Eclipse it crashes sending some message like this:

> "(OperationalError): unable to open database file."

I did some research and it turned out to be a dead end, so a tried to deploy using Maven command on terminal `$ mvn appengine:deploy` and it works, but when I access the generated URL it sends me an error message [App Engine Error Screenshot Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2UkD.png).

I'm guessing it has something to do with Tomcat, because of this weird error message and for the fact that GAE does not use it and I used while developing, but I excluded all Maven dependencies related to it, so I feel really lost on this one.

Just so you know, no error reporting is shown on GCP Console or App Engine Dashboard, the only message I receive is this weird one.

Comment: Are you following any documentation?

Comment: First, thanks for the edit Dave, that became really easier to see, and yes, i'm using this doc [Deploying Java App to GAE Using Maven](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/maven?hl=pt-br). I took some time to look at the logs of GCP, and some message about a duplicate SLF4J dependency is being displayed, so now i'm trying to fix that to see what happens...

Comment: Well, if you check the link you provided in english language is a deprecated documentation. Are you using standard or flex? In case of standard I advise you to follow this [github's code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/appengine-standard-java8/springboot-appengine-standard) tutorial, which was really helpful to me.

Comment: Thank you very much @TasosV i'm using the standard one. That's exactly what i needed, all errors are gone now, thanks man!

Comment: I am glad that I was able to help you. I posted my comment as an answer and you can accepted as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the documentation you followed was deprecated, the best way to proceed with your scenario is to follow the example code provided by [Google](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/appengine-standard-java8/springboot-appengine-standard) in Github about App Engine Standard with SpringBoot.